# VSCode - Call to undefined function in imported module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-import

If I write this code:

```py
import math
math.abcdef()
```

where clearly the method `abcdef()` does not exist in the imported `math` module, why doesn't visual studio code show an error?

Is there a way to force vscode to check that the called method exists in the imported module?

Comment: When I run on my machine: `AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'abcdef'`. Also, the function appears in different color depending on whether its a recognized function or not.

Comment: If I select as Linter pylint I got the same AttributeError as you. 
With pycodestyle no errors..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such error messages in vscode are generally provided by **linting**.

You can enable **linting** in settings. The error messages obtained by selecting different linter are not exactly the same.

[image]

If you don't want use **linting**, change the **python.analysis.typeCheckingMode** option in the settings to `basic` or `strict`.

[image]

At this point, the **Python** extension prompts an error message.

[image]
*`basic`*

[image]
*`strict`*

Comment: Indeed the key was to understand that not all the linter show the same errors: pycodestyle shows errors regarding the formatting style, while pylint or flake8 also provide type checking errors. For anyone who's setting up a linter, also be careful to check both User and Workspace settings.